# How to get text channels from specific server?

Tags: discord.py

How to get text channels from specific server ? pls help me

```
async def memberjoin(ctx, channel : str):
    id = ctx.message.guild.id
    text_channel_list = []
    for guild in client.get_guild(id):
        for channel in client.text_channels:
            text_channel_list.append(channel)

    for i in range(len(text_channel_list)):
        if text_channel_list[i] == channel:
            await ctx.send(f"channel set to {channel}")
            break
        else:
            await ctx.send("channel ver moidzebna")
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through all the guilds that the bot is in as so:

```
for guild in client.guilds:
    if guild.name == "the name of the guild":
        textChannels = guild.text_channels
```

You can replace `guild.name` with other things such as `id`, you should check the [`documentation`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guilds#discord.Guild)

Comment: Thanks Nuke Fluffy

Comment: No problem, make sure to mark the answer as the solution if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get the `text_channels` of the guild where the command was used

```py
text_channels = ctx.guild.text_channels
```

Also here's a better solution to your code:

```py
@client.command()
# We're passing a `discord.TextChannel` object as the channel variable
async def member_join(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    await ctx.send(f'Channel set to {channel.mention}')
    # Do whatever you want with `channel`
    # If the user passes a wrong argument `commands.BadArgument` is going to be thrown
```

#### Reference:

- [`Guild.text_channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20text#discord.Guild.text_channels)
- [`Converters`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=type%20hints#converters)
- [`commands.BadArgument`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=badargument#discord.ext.commands.BadArgument)